# Obtaining the fields using the ListView class from Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm learning to manage the `ListView class` from `django`, obtain the data is really easy.

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Fleet

class fleet_bbdd_view(ListView):
    template_name = 'data_app/fleets-bbdd.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    model = Fleet
    context_object_name = 'FleetsList'
```

But what I can't find is how to obtain the fields of my model and pass they in my context object. Is possible to do this using the `ListView class` ?

I know how to obtain it, in a normal function, but if it is possible I prefer to use `ListView class`.

```
def getData(request):
    cols = [i.name for i in Fleet._meta.get_fields()]
    ctx = {'Cols':cols}
    return JsonResponse(ctx)
```

Can somebody help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: A `ListView` inherits from [`ContextMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#contextmixin) so you can override `get_context_data()` to add anything you like to the context.

Answer (score 1):

As @dirkgroten said you can override `get_context_data()` but calling its super. Here is a good place to look at the functions you can override and what they do: https://ccbv.co.uk/.

If you only need to use the `Fleet` objects in your template, you have named them `FleetsList` by doing `context_object_name = 'FleetsList'`. This will add the list objects to the context similar to `context = {'FleetsList': queryset}`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you're trying to get the field names into your context. You can do this similarly to how you set the `cols` variable in your question, but you need to override get_context_data() to get it into the context, like @dirkgroten said.

```
class fleet_bbdd_view(ListView):
    template_name = 'data_app/fleets-bbdd.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    model = Fleet
    context_object_name = 'FleetsList'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cols'] = [i.name for i in Fleet._meta.get_fields()]
        return context
```